# image move with mouse move

Tags: jquery, mousemove

using say jQuery, how do I have an image move with the mouse (or rather the cursor) i.e. such that the image is glued to the pointer; how do I later un-glue it, or swap the glued image. thanks

Comment: It would be a combination of the `mousemove()` and `click()`events. Have a read of the in the API: http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a custom cursor image? Or are you looking to drag and move an image thats already on your page?

If its the former, you can use `cursor: url(cursor.cur);` in your css file.

If its the latter, you can do it be appropriately handling the `image's mousedown` and the `document's mousemove and mouseup` events.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery ui you could use:

apply the following (or a versionof it) on mousedown:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(ev){
  $("#theimage").position({
    my: "left bottom",
    of: ev,
    collision: "fit"
  });
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position

and set absoulute position of the image on mouseup.